# Using an array to apply multiple mixins

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using ES6 is there a way to apply multiple mixins which are defined in an array? The mixins would be defined as such:

```
const mixins = Array('Mixin', 'Mixin2');
```

Then creating a mixin with:

```
export const Mixin = function (superClass) {
return class extends superClass {}
```

And using the mixin with:

```
export class MyClass extends MultipleMixins(BaseClass)
```

Comment: It's better to not modify the hosted objects and built-in types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` over the array of mixins, pass in a base class and keep returning a new mixed class. This will just apply all the mixing in order:

```js
class BaseClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}

// adds an uppercase
const Mixin = function(superClass) {
  return class extends superClass {
    get uppercase() {
      this.name = this.name.toUpperCase()
      return this
    }
  }
}

//adds a reverse
const Mixin2 = function(superClass) {
  return class extends superClass {
    get reverse() {
      this.name = [...this.name].reverse().join('')
      return this
    }
  }
}

let mixins = [Mixin, Mixin2]

let MixedClass = mixins.reduce((base, mix) => mix(base), BaseClass)

let instance = new MixedClass('mark')
// use the new methods
console.log("reversed & uppercase:", instance.uppercase.reverse.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would there be any way to achieve this syntax:

    class MyClass extends 
    MultipleMixinFunction([Mixin1, Mixin2], 
    BaseClass)

Comment: Got it:
    const Mixin = (mixins, baseClass) => 
    mixins.reduce((base, mixin) => mixin(base), baseClass);